# Using page-specific scripts with Symfony 5 and WebPack in inline script (twig template)

Tags: php, symfony, webpack

I'm trying to use page-specific module with inline script but getting an error.

At first I have created a module and stored it in `assets/js/tags.js`

```
class TaggedImage {
    constructor(image) {
        this.image = image
    }
    ...
}
export {TaggedImage}
```

Then I added this module in webpack.config.js to specific route:

```js
Encore
    ...
    .addEntry('photo_page', './assets/js/tags.js')
```

Now I'm trying to use this module with inline script in twig template:

```html
<script>
    const myImage = new TaggedImage(document.getElementById('photoImage'));
    const tags = [
            {x:0.5, y:0.5, width:0.15, height:0.22},
            {x:0.65, y:0.33, width:0.13, height:0.19},
            {x:0.1222, y:0.398, width:0.10, height:0.335}
        ];
    myImage.addTags(tags).render();
</script>
```

Then I ran `npm run dev` in the terminal and it finished without errors.

...and after refreshing the page I get an error in the console:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: TaggedImage is not defined

I noticed that my code is added to `/public/build/photo_page.js` but I don't see any mention of this file in page source.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There are two things to your problem.
The first one is that besides defining the entry in `webpack.config`, you have to explicitly import your javascript in your html.

You can do that with the twig helper function `encore_entry_script_tags` as described in the [page specific scripts](https://symfony.com/doc/current/frontend/encore/simple-example.html#page-specific-javascript-or-css-multiple-entries) section of the manual.

So you would add:

```
{{ encore_entry_script_tags('photo_page') }}
<script>
// Here goes your script
</script>
```

Or override your block, if you have one, and call `{{ parent() }}` to include any additional scripts you require in all pages.
Note that the `entry` tag will add the `defer` attribute by default, as configured in `config/packages/webpack_encore.yaml`, so you'll need to take that into account and wrap your script to fire on the `load` event.

The second one is that webpack doesn't expose modules to the global namespace. For that you would have to do it explicitly in your module:

```
// Instead of exporting the module, you export it to the global scope
// (the browser window in this case)
global.TaggedImage = TaggedImage;
```

Comment: Thanks! Worked like a charm. Also I had to wrap my inline code into ```window.onload = function() { ... }```

Comment: @NikitaBulatenko yes, that's because `encore_entry_script_tags` adds the attribute `defer` by default. This is controlled by the `config/packages/webpack_encore.yaml` configuration file.